# Git + Eclipse: 401 Unauthorized Error

Tags: eclipse, git, apache, eclipse-plugin, smart-http

I have a git repo on my rasperry pi, with Apache. 
I use git + smart http: from a Linux client, using a Terminal, all work fine. 
For example I can clone a repo using the command:

```
git clone http://address:8080/git/repo_name
```

After the insertion of the username and password, it works.

But, if I want to clone the repo using Eclipse, it shows this error:

[image]

This is the error log of apache:

```
[Wed Sep 28 12:33:13.321726 2016] [negotiation:error] [pid 28020] [client 131.114.176.222:37524] AH00690: no acceptable variant: /usr/share/httpd/error/HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED.html.var
```

And this is my apache configuration (about git and smart http):

```
<Directory "/usr/lib/git-core*">
   Options ExecCGI Indexes
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>

<LocationMatch "^/.*/git-receive-pack$">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Login"
    AuthUserFile /srv/git/.git-auth-file
    Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^/.*/git-upload-pack$">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Login"
    AuthUserFile /srv/git/.git-auth-file
    Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /srv/git
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/
```

Any ideas?

PS: I'm using

- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Neon Release (4.6.0) Build id: 20160613-1800
- EGit 4.4.0.20160607

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same problem, I have read that it´s an eclipse bug, there is a fix in progress https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/82187/.

For now, you can fix the problem installing "EPP MArketplace Client". In your eclipse click Help -> Install New Software and put the follow url: http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/releases/1.5.2/, then install.

Comment: Thanks a Lot!.. I faced this problem too on Oxygen [4.7.0 M2]. After installing the said software it started working!.